# Hide TitleBar + ZIndex

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I've tried to hide TitleBar by :

```
private void Visibility_TitleBar(bool visible) {
   var coreTitleBar = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
   coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = !visible;
}
```

[image: TitleBar]

problems : it's not possible to press Menu Button cause it seems like titlebar is in front of the button (or having higher ZIndex).

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : 
Add a rectangle to MainPage for customizing titlebar. (with left margin -to not overlay menu button)

[image: Rectangle]

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="MyTitleBar" Margin="48,0,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="36" Canvas.ZIndex="100"/>
```

Then this code will place your rectangle as titlebar.

```
private void Visibility_TitleBar(bool visible) {
    var coreTitleBar = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = !visible;
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(MyTitleBar);
}
```